# How to calculate the user(client) device width and height in PHP?

Tags: php

In fact I want to know that:
If the device width is smaller than height, so the device is a tablet or a mobile phone in standard position and rotation (usually) . Is this idea true? So Can I change the background image for a div when the device width is smaller than height?
I know I should do this with JQuery , but learning jquery is for the next step!
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do that in php. Clients do not expose such information in HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you *should* do this in jQuery and/or, better yet, CSS. PHP is the absolutely wrong place to do this, because PHP has absolutely zero information on the specifics of where its output is going to be rendered. [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) were designed to let you alter presentation based on attributes of the client, like screen size.

Comment: In fact I want to change my website background in mobile phone or tablet, I think it's not  possible in css. Is it?

Comment: It is perfectly possible. Google for *"responsive design"*, it's all about this topic.